# How to assign a very large number to BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger, value-of

Given the following input:

```
4534534534564657652349234230947234723947234234823048230957349573209483057
12324000123123
```

I have attempted to assign these values to `BigInteger` in the following way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        BigInteger num1 = BigInteger.valueOf(sc.nextLong());
        sc.nextLine();
        BigInteger num2 = BigInteger.valueOf(sc.nextLong());

        BigInteger additionTotal = num1.add(num2);
        BigInteger multiplyTotal = num1.multiply(num2);

        System.out.println(additionTotal);
        System.out.println(multiplyTotal);
    }
```

The first value is outside of the boundaries for a Long number, and so I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input
>   string:
>   "4534534534564657652349234230947234723947234234823048230957349573209483057"

I assumed that BigInteger expects a Long type for use with `valueOf()` method (as stated [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_valueof.htm)). How can I pass extremely large numbers to BigInteger?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the input number does not fit in `long`, [use the constructor that takes a `String` argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)):

```
String numStr = "453453453456465765234923423094723472394723423482304823095734957320948305712324000123123";
BigInteger num = new BigInteger(numStr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the huge number in as a String.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.nextLine();
    BigInteger num1 = new BigInteger(s);

    s = in.nextLine();
    BigInteger num2 = new BigInteger(s);

    //do stuff with num1 and num2 here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the String contructor: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)

```
      public BigInteger(String val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the string constructor.

Like this.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)

If the long datatype could handle arbitrarily large numbers, there would be no need for a BigInteger.